# Yarn cannot install angular library from local directory

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, package.json

I have an angular workspace with library project 'cd-lib'.  I am using yarn as package manager. On another angular project, I am trying to install the cd-lib from a local directory.
When I run

```
yarn add ./libs/cd-lib
```

,
the output is as follows:

```
⋊> ~/cdShell on main ⨯ yarn add ./libs/cd-lib                                                                                                   11:52:21
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error <home-directory>/cdShell/libs@0.0.0: Name contains illegal characters
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

On the library, the pageckage manager setting for name and version is as follows:

```
  "name": "cd-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
```

Both the library project and the one where I am trying to install the library, are running angular 11.
Any clue on what may cause the error **'Name contains illegal characters'**.
While trying to check the common cause I see white space or use of capital case. In my case, I have not used any of this in the naming. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try `yarn add file:./libs/cd-lib`?

Comment: I have just tried that.  Getting same results with the same error message: Name contains illegal characters